# Error CS1733: Expected Expression error in writing data in a single row

Tags: c#, excel, compiler-errors, range, cell

I'm creating a software using C# that transfers data to an excel file. I want to write different data values in a single range of row.

I've tried to create variables since some parts have the same syntax.

This is my code:

```
var reflection193 = arLot.ARResultModel.FirstOrDefault(rm => rm.ResultType == ResultType.Reflection193);
Worksheet.Range["C23", "D23"].Value =
                    ("{0} %", "{1} %", (reflection193)?.LowerValue, (reflection193)?.UpperValue);
```

I expect to have Lower value in cell C23 and Upper value in cell D23 in the excel result. What I'm getting is an "Error cs1733: expected expression". Plus I'm also having an Exception thrown: "'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll" and
"Exception: Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: (reflection193)?.LowerValue and (reflection193)?.UpperValue) are arguments that are not used in format String

Comment: It's telling you that is not valid C# code. What is your intent? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to write  multiple data into a single row. So the range would be from C23 to D23. The values of these cells  has some syntax similarites so I compiled them in a variable.

Comment: What type does `.Value` expect?

Comment: the values would be in double

Comment: Right, but what is the exact type of the `Value` property? You can put your mouse cursor over it and Visual Studio will tell you.

Comment: dynamic Range.Value[[object RangeValueDataType]] {get; set:}